# how to pass parent Id from component and show child records on vfpage

Tags: visualforce-component

I have created component and create attribute

```
<apex:attribute name="parentId" description="Parent Id get"
 type="Id" assignTo="{!parentId}"  />
```

and create parentId variable in class
how to do get parentid from component

complete code of **Component**

```
<apex:component controller="PaginationSortingController">
    <style type="text/css">
        .textalign {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:attribute name="pId" description="Parent Id get" type="Id" assignTo="{!parentId}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="parentId" value="{!pId}" />
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:pageBlock id="pgblock">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Details -  Page #{!pageNumber}" columns="1" collapsible="false">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Contacts}" var="conList" rules="groups" title="Click Column Header for Sorting" styleclass="textalign" headerClass="textalign">
                    <apex:column>
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            Action
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Edit" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <apex:commandButton value="Delete" />
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column>
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:commandLink value="FirstName" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="pgblock">
                                <apex:param name="sortField" value="First Name" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                            </apex:commandLink>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!conList.FirstName}" />
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column>
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:commandLink value="Last Name" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="pgblock">
                                <apex:param name="sortField" value="Last Name" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                            </apex:commandLink>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!conList.LastName}" />
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column>
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:commandLink value="Email" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="pgblock">
                                <apex:param name="sortField" value="Email" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                            </apex:commandLink>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!conList.Email}" />
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column>
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:commandLink value="Salary" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="pgblock">
                                <apex:param name="sortField" value="Salary__c" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                            </apex:commandLink>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!conList.Salary__c}" />
                    </apex:column>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:panelGrid columns="4">
                <!--<apex:commandLink action="{!first}">First</apex:commandlink>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}" rendered="{!hasPrevious}">Previous</apex:commandlink>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!next}" rendered="{!hasNext}">Next</apex:commandlink>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!last}">Last</apex:commandlink> -->

                <apex:commandButton status="fetching" reRender="form" value="First" immediate="true" action="{!first}" disabled="{!!hasPrevious }" title="First Page" />

                <apex:commandButton status="fetching" reRender="form" value="Previous" immediate="true" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!!hasPrevious }" title="Previous Page" />

                <apex:commandButton status="fetching" reRender="form" value="Next" immediate="true" action="{!next}" disabled="{!!hasNext}" title="Next Page" />

                <apex:commandButton status="fetching" reRender="form" value="Last" immediate="true" action="{!last}" disabled="{!!hasNext}" title="Last Page" />

            </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

here is **Class** code

```
public class PaginationSortingController {
    public String soql {get;set;}
    public List<Contact> con1 = New List<Contact>();
    public String soqlsort {get;set;}
    public List<Contact> con2 = New List<Contact>();
    public Id parentId {get;set;}
    public PaginationSortingController() {}
    public List < Contact > getContacts() {
        if (parentId == null)
            parentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('parentId');
        return Con.getRecords();
    }
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController con {
        get {
            System.debug('===' + parentId);
            if (con == null) {

                soql = 'SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email , Salary__c FROM Contact WHERE  AccountId =: parentId';

                con1 = Database.query(soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir);

                con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(con1);

                con.setPageSize(4);
            }
            return con;
        }
        set;
    }
    public Boolean hasNext {
        get {
            return con.getHasNext();
        }
        set;
    }
    public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get {
            return con.getHasPrevious();
        }
        set;
    }
    public Integer pageNumber {
        get {
            return con.getPageNumber();
        }
        set;
    }
    public void first() {
        con.first();
    }
    public void last() {
        con.last();
    }
    public void previous() {
        con.previous();
    }
    public void next() {
        con.next();
    }
    public void cancel() {
        con.cancel();
    }
    public void toggleSort() {
        sortDir = sortDir.equals('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        soqlsort = 'SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email , Salary__c FROM Contact WHERE  AccountId =: parentId';
        con2 = Database.query(soqlsort + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir);
        con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(con2);
        con.setPageSize(4);
    }
    public String sortDir {
        get {
            if (sortDir == null) {
                sortDir = 'asc';
            }
            return sortDir;
        }
        set;
    }
    public String sortField {
        get {
            if (sortField == null) {
                sortField = 'FirstName';
            }
            return sortField;
        }
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your complete component code. what I am understanding that you want to pass your parent id in component and inside component you want to show all child record is that correct ?

Comment: added component code

Comment: this is work for account and contact but i want any parent and its child. means dynamicaly work